# How does a foreach loop iterate through an object

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, foreach

I am getting the contents of a facebook api call that will return all the posts made to a facebook group. So all the posts/comments on that post.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2));

foreach($data as $post){
    foreach $post as $subpost)
    {
     ...etc
    }
}
```

The problem I have here is that I will need to use 3 nested `foreach` loops in order to actually get the data I want. How do I get the first element of `$data` without having to use a `foreach`?

e.g. something like `$data[0]` (which doesn't work). How does a `foreach` loop iterate through an object so I can just manually write it since I only want 1 single object thats nested inside arrays.

edit 
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["data"]=> array(25) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (10)...

i want to access the final object that contains 10 pieces of data.

Comment: can you show the `var_dump($data)`

Comment: Yes, show what the data looks like if you want a solution

Comment: sidenote: you can use `json_decode($return_value, true)`, to make it an array if objects bothers you

Answer (score 2):

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);`

will return an array and you can access it via an index like `$data[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like below - just pass true in second argument , it will convert object into array so you can use it as array.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);
foreach($data as $post){
    foreach $post as $subpost)
    {
        ...etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2),true);
```

To convert it to a array then try

$data[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$post` instead of $data..
indexing of `$post` depends on what kind of data you are receiving through json.
If it is a 2-dimensional array,You can use `$post[0]['index']` or if it is a single-dimensional array,you can use `$post['index']`, which will give you the exact indexed item.